# Registering a business or community page on Google+ when personal account is rejected

Tags: google-plus

I want to create a Google+ account for my community, but Google rejects my account because I do not enter a real name.

How can I create an account on Google Plus for my community like [TechCrunch](https://plus.google.com/+TechCrunch/) has, not for me as person?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy. Just register as yourself, then create the page.

If you can't use your real name for political reasons (e.g. fear of torture, etc), use a pseudonym.